# How can I get the column name along with its reference type (i.e PRIMARY KEY & FOREIGN KEY) in a single POSTGRESQL Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I came up with the following query which provides me the column names along with its data-types but does not provide me the reference type(i.e whether the column is a primary_key or a foreign_key).

```
select column_name, data_type,character_maximum_length,is_nullable
from   information_schema.columns
where  table_name ='employee';
```

This is the Output that I am getting:

```
 column_name |     data_type     | character_maximum_length | is_nullable
-------------+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------
 empno       | character varying |                       10 | NO
 full_name   | character varying |                       30 | YES
 city        | character varying |                        9 | YES
 gender      | character         |                        7 | YES
```

Can someone help me out getting the reference_type (i.e **PRIMARY_KEY** & **FOREIGN_KEY**) as well for the query?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) Also asked on dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/184065/1822

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no one replied at database administrator hence was compelled to post it here in the main one.

Comment: @sagi: I really don't think my question is a duplicate of the one you have posted the link of.
What I am looking for is having the tables column along with their reference type. Had already visited https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns but that really didnt fulfil my purpose hence posted the question according to the one which fulfilled my needs.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, it shows you from where you can get this information, just use joins. Nevertheless , I opened the questioned if you still hasn't got your answer from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 select c.column_name, c.data_type, c.character_maximum_length, c.is_nullable, s.constraint_name, t.constraint_type
    from   information_schema.columns c
    left join information_schema.key_column_usage s on s.table_name = c.table_name and s.column_name = c.column_name
    left join information_schema.table_constraints t on t.table_name = c.table_name and t.constraint_name = s.constraint_name
    where  c.table_name ='employee'
```

Have a look at this link
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/information-schema.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name & N.Dov: Bullseye...This is the exact thing that I was looking for. Thanks a ton Man :) :) :)